# Django - prevent CreateView being called twice

Tags: python, django, django-views

What I need to do is access the same CreateView from two different pages.  One of those two pages will send along some data that will be inserted into the CreateView form via get_initial().  The button I'm using to access the view is sending some POST data and so the CreateView is immediately thinking everything was successful and going all the way to get_success_url() and then rerouting.  Below is what I have.  I'm not sure the most elegant way to achieve what I wanted.  I was trying to avoid any GET data (making the URLs messy) if possible?  This there an elegant way to send POST data to the CreateView upon initialization?

template.html

```html
            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'purification:add' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="sample_id" value="{{ sample_data.id }}">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="add-purification-button" role="button" type="submit">+Add Purification</button>
</form>
```

view.py

```
class PurificationCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Purification
    template_name = "add_purification.html"
    fields = "__all__"

    def get_initial(self):
        if self.request.POST.get('sample_id'):
            sample = Samples.objects.get(pk=self.request.POST['sample_id'])
            return {'sample': sample}

        return None

    def get_success_url(self):
        if "save-and-add-another" in self.request.POST:
            return reverse('purification:add')
        else:
            return reverse('samples:oneSample', kwargs={'sample_id': self.request.POST['sample']})
```

Comment: In general, if you're POSTing to a CreateView, that should *always* result in a create, and probably a redirect. If `PurificationCreateView` need to pull information from a `Samples` model, anything that POSTs to `Samples` should probably be using separate `SampleCreate`/`SampleUpdate` views.

Comment: Ya what's happening is that a purification may or may not have a foreign key to a sample.  I tried having def post() in the OneSample view collect the button's POST, and redirect to PurificationCreateView from there, but couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason you shouldn't be able to have your `SampleCreate` redirect on success to `PurificationCreate`. If it's not working you can ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Well it's a general SampleView with an Add Purification button underneath, but the real issue is how to send data from one view to another which would be an issue regardless.

Comment: Very hard to answer without more code showing the relationship between the views, but *in general* if `JacketView` needs the shirt that `ShirtView` created, the whatever is posting to `JacketView` should include the parameters `JacketView` needs in order to find the right `shirt` instance. Eg, the URL might be: `/myclothes/shirts/5/jackets`, then `JacketView` can tell from the URL that it should retrieve shirt #5 from the database.